# Can someone explain these theorems to me (I have not been able to understand them very well).

Tags: axiom-of-choice, well-orders

Let $A$ be an arbitrary set. We will consider pairs $(B, G)$, where $B$ is a subset of $A$, and $G$ is an order relation in $B$ which well-orders $B$.

Let  $\mathscr{A}$ be the family of all such pairs $(B, G)$. We introduce the symbol and define $(B, G)\prec (B′,G′)$ if
and only if,

- $B\subseteq B'.$
- $G\subseteq G'.$
- $x\in B$ and $y\in B'-B\Rightarrow (x,y)\in G'$.

> **Lemma 1.0:** Let $$\mathscr{C}=\{(B_i,G_i)\}_{i\in I}$$ be chain of $\mathscr{A}$, let $$B=\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\quad\text{and}\quad G=\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i.$$ Then $(B,G)\in \mathscr{A}.$

**Lemma 1.1:** If $\mathscr{C},B,G$ are defined as above, $(B, G)$ is an upper bound of $\mathscr{C}$.

**Proof:** Let $(B_i,G_i) \in \mathscr{C}$; clearly $B_i\subseteq B$ and $G_i\subseteq G$. Now suppose that $x\in B_i$, $y \in B$, and $y\notin B_i$; certainly $y\in B_j$ for some $j\in I$. So $(B_j, G_j) \nprec(B_i,G_i)$, hence $(B_i
,G_i)\prec (B_j, G_j)$. Now $x \in B_i$ and $y \in (B_j − B_i
)$, so, $(x, y) \in G_j \subseteq G$. Thus $(B_i,G_i)\prec (B, G)$.

> **Commentary:** From this proof, what is going to be demonstrated there is that given any two elements of $ \mathscr{C} $ (In this case
> its elements are $ (B_i, G_i) $), then those two elements can be
> compared with $ (B, G) $ under the operation defined above (or we are
> going to denote them arbitrarily less that $ (B, G) $), am I correct?
> And the other thing is the piece that says, "So $(B_j, G_j) \nprec(B_i,G_i)$, hence $(B_i
> ,G_i)\prec (B_j, G_j)$", I don't understand why
> that is followed.

**Theorem:** Any set $A$ can be well ordered.

**Proof:** By lemma 1.0 and 1.1, we can apply Zorn’s Lemma to $\mathscr{A}$ ; thus has a maximal element $(B,G)$. We will show that $B = A$; hence $A$ can be well-ordered. Otherwise, $\exists x ∈ (A − B)$; by defining $x$ to be greater than each element of $B$, we get an extension $G^∗$ of $G$ that well-orders $B \cup \{x\}$. (More explicitly,
$G^∗ = G \cup \{(a, x) : a \in B\}.$) This is a contradiction, since $(B, G)$ was assumed to be maximal.

> **Commentary.** The part about the Zorn’s Lemma being applied to it is easy to understand since with the lemma 1.0 and 1.1 we have shown that $(\mathscr{A},\prec)$ is a nonempty ordered set such that every well-ordered subset of $ $ has an upper bound (this makes it in an "inductive" set) and Zorn’s Lemma says that every inductive set has a maximal element, in that case it's $ (B, G) $, I think I'm correct. But the remaining part in which they define $ x $ I don't understand, why they define it that way and why it contradicts the maximal element, someone explains that part to me.

Comment: Which part is unclear exactly?

Comment: In my comments that I made to the proof, he left my doubts, because both in the lemma and in the theorem I have some gaps. I would also like you to tell me if my reasoning in the comments is good, since this motto is quite important, and I would like to be quite clear about it. @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea in a nutshell.

We order subsets of $A$ with well-orders, and we extend them "on the top of each other". We then claim that this partial order satisfies the conditions of Zorn's lemma, then a maximal element must have as the domain of the order the entirety of $A$, since otherwise we can pick an element not ordered, put it "on top" of the order, and we have a strictly larger well-ordered subset of $A$. This is the usual maximality trick. The same as in the proof that every vector space has a basis, for example.

I think that a better way is to actually look at this proof from the eyes of transfinite recursion. We fix a choice function from subsets of $A$, and then we use to generate a well-ordering, one step at a time, by choosing an element from the part we haven't ordered yet. This way we build the order literally one element at a time, until we exhaust the entirety of $A$, in which case we got what we wanted: a well-ordering of the whole of $A$.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph. That's a matter of which way you prove that AoC, WoT and ZL all imply eachother. The OP proof proves ZL implies WoT, your final paragraph proves AoC implies WoT. So it's a different result, unless you have already proven that ZL and AoC are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, obviously. But once you understand that any proof using ZL can be done with AC and transfinite recursion directly, it frees you from the somewhat rigid thinking of ZL.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to clarify the demo for me. I appreciate. :)